# Magento 2 Price filter code

Tags: magento2, filter

I want to make some changes to the price filter code so my question is: Where can I find all the code that is related to the Category Price Filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should find in `vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation`.

Then, see some files:

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price/Range.php`

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/DataProvider/Price.php`

`vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Adapter/Options.php`